# how to create a multidimensional json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
var items = [{
    title: 'sample 1',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 2',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 3',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 4',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/600/600/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 5',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/310/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 6',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/410/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 7',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 8',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 9',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/450/320/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 10',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/400/'
}];
```

Instead of hard coding this, I would like to create this exact same array dynamically - here is my code.

```
for(var key in pics) {
    var items[];
    items.push(pics[key].source);
}
```

I dont think this works because it just pushes the images into a standard array like this:

```
items = [1.jpg, 2.jpg....];
```

How can I accomplish this,cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you get the img url and i assume pics.source is the title:

```
var items = [];
for(var key in pics) {
    items.push({title: pics[key].source, image: <img url>});
}
```

Comment: Im fetching the img url remotely